# Bash: How do I move my cursor to the left a word-at-a-time?

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts

In OSX I can just hold down the <kbd>option</kbd> key and press the left cursor key until I get to the word I need to edit (or in Vi I can just hit <kbd>b</kbd>, but I haven't been able to figure out how to do this in Terminal yet...

Comment: You can see the full list of readline bindings [on this page](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl3_readline.htm), including instructions how to customize your own bindings.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To set the key binding: You first have to find out what key codes the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> key sequence creates. Just use the command `cat` to switch off any interference with existing key bindings, and then type the key sequence. In my system (Linux), this looks like that:

```
$ cat
^[[1;5D
```

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> to exit cat. Now you have found out that Ctrl-Left issues 6 key codes:

- Escape (^[)
- [
- 1
- ;
- 5
- D

Now you can issue the bind command:

```
bind '"\e[1;5D": backward-word'
```

Comment: You can add `` "\e[1;5D": backward-word '' into $HOME/.inputrc for permanent effect if you want .

Comment: @llhuii +1, I forgot to mention that!

Comment: +1 for the most flexible way to bind arbitrary key combinations anywhere!

Comment: if-my-word-contains-dashes - can I create a hotkey for a such?

Answer (score 16):

The bash function you want is `backward-word`. You can run `bind -q backward-word` to get a list of keys bound to that function. One common binding is <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>

Also, many terminals support <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> (the same hotkey you can use in X to jump backwards by word)

Comment: Ok, it returns `backward-word can be invoked via "\eb".` but how do  I bind control+Left instead of Esc+b? Also, one drawback to Esc+b I can already see is that I have to let up on the Esc key every time I can to go back a word, isn't there a better way?

Comment: Is there a better way? Naturally: `set editing-mode vi` :)

Comment: @nipponese "esc b" can also be used on the keyboard as ALT-b. This may need to be specifically the left or right alt depending on your configuration, so try both.

Answer (score 9):

The default key shortcut in Bash for `backword-word` is <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd> . The same result can be achived with <kbd>Esc</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd> . You should give those a try before editing your keybindings.

Use `bind` command to edit or `bind -q [name]` to get the current keybind of a specific action.

Comment: ... and forward - `Alt + f`